# Use this selector in on method

Tags: jquery

I would like to handle a click event on a element dynamically created and which can only be selected with `this`. Here is my code :

```
$.fn.checkbox = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        $this = $(this)

        $(document).on('click', this, function(){
            // My code here
        })
    })
}
```

But this code doesn't seem to work. Any idea how I could do ?

Comment: This doesnt make much sense... you target the element you created via a class or id, not `this`

Comment: My code is in a plugin and I don't know the selector...

Comment: If you already have a reference to `this` there's zero point in using event delegation; bind a regular old event handler to it.

Comment: jQuery click events are targeted through class or id like @tymeJV said. Javascript onclick events are what you are looking for. To use `this` you have to be targeting the element directly.

Comment: Could you give me an example of code because I have difficulties to understand...

Comment: `.on(event, selector, function)` is used to bind event on element that are dynamics (elements that are not present when interpreting the line). If you have access to `this` (which you have), there is no point in using delegatation. You should bind directly on it : `$(this).on(event, function);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **all** you have to refer to the element is `this`, then you're stuck with using plain (non-delegated) event handlers. That's not a problem, however, because *the element will already exist* when the code runs. We know this because you have a reference to it, and you can't have a reference to it if it doesn't exist.

However, you're trying to do this inside a jQuery plugin function, in which case `this` in that context is actually a jQuery object. That's why you can call `this.each(...);` in your code in the question. To bind the event handlers, you can just do:

```
this.on('click', function(e) {
    // your event handler code here
});
```

Inside the context of that handler function, `this` will refer to the element clicked on, so it's not the same as the `this` that you called `.on()` on.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misunderstood how my code was working. I have to find an other way of doing...